# Error when injecting angular-animate.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I am receiving the following error when injecting `angular-animate.js`:
`Unknown provider: $animateProvider from ngAnimate`

Here is my app.js:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngAnimate"])
```

Here is head of `index.html`:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding-bottom: 70px">
```

Bootstrap alone is loaded fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LV1edcHGv9qr1KxMopsx)

Comment: Can you jsFiddle/plnkr the problem

Comment: @smk i edited the questions, added at the bottom, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a different error with your code.  I got a missing `$routeProvider` error.

As the first line of your app.js try this:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"])
```

instead of

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"])
```

And add it your header:

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-route.js"></script>
```

By the way, using the non-minified version of Angular in plnkr.co gives a more human readable error message in these cases.

Comment: I used the google hosted code from the plnkr, in my local code and now  i get the `Error: [$injector:modulerr]`... and error is the same when I add `"ngRoute"`

Comment: Forgot to mention including it.  I just added that- see if including angular-routes.js fixes it (looks like it works for me- leaving you with an error in AppCtrl).

Comment: Oh, and google hosts both a minified and non-minified version.  Just remove the .min and you'll get nicer error messages (src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js")

Comment: Here's a plunker with the changes I described: http://plnkr.co/edit/nni8MlsLGjIiI3BrkjMN?p=preview

Comment: Great, all fixed, except bootstrap is not executing now, do you think it's some inconsistencies beetween these two, or is it something i can fix on my end? thanks a lot! sorry

Comment: Seems to work to me.  I just added a bootstrap button and a bootstrap-ui button group to that plunker (so you can take a look).  And both appear to work to me.  Do you have an example of what's failing for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring app.js before the angular-animate library. Try this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding-bottom: 70px">
```