# Strange error in angular-animate.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I try to use ngAnimate module to create a simple animation. The problem is that every time I try to just include this module as a dependency I got this error: `Error: Unknown provider: $animateProvider from ngAnimate`.

The code is very simple, but I can't get what is the problem.

Here is my HTML template:

```
<html>
    <head>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/angular-animate.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <!-- And so on -->

</html>
```

And I include ngAnimation in my module like this:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);
```

Quite simple. Everything is like in [this](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-animation-basics) tutorial, nothing special. But it doesn't work. The same problem was on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412531/error-when-injecting-angular-animate-js), but useless...

So, can anybody explain me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce that in Plunker/Fiddle?

Comment: I've already posted important thing in my code...

Comment: can you tell us which versions of angular do you use ? I have the same error with the 1.2.0-rc.3 from bower.

Answer (score 2):

All in all the problem was fixed by migrating to 1.2.13 version of AngularJS. I think that this error was occured bacause 1.0.8 doens't support it (or maybe it was some thing else).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by updating to angular 1.2.13. Seems that for me was due to mismatching versions between angular 1.0.8 etc.

Comment: I had the same problem. It looks like 1.0.8 doesn't support this feature at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this type of error is usually due to wrong file references. Are you sure the path to angular-animate.js is correct? does it point to the right file? is the file present in your directory?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting another answer that helped me for future watchers of this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24766563/1366216

Ran into the same problem. You have to match the version of angular to angular animate.
change:
"angular-animate": "1.2.6"

Crux is that you need to match angular version with angular-animate version.